# Procedural Breakout level generation

Tags: procedural-generation, procedural

I am currently developing a Breakout game for a school project, and I've decided to use it as an opportunity to get started with procedural content generation. I took a quick look at some of the basic procedural stuff, but I wanted to know if there is a known good method to generate levels for this kind of game (block patterns, "power up" distribution, etc).
Any articles or ideas are greatly appreciated.